# Why PHP doesn't handle $_POST data containing ampersand "&" while php://input contains all data?

Tags: php, csv, post

I am having strange problem with POST data in PHP. Whenever POST data contains '&' (ampersand character) it starts to behave very strangely. Please see example below.

Data which are POSTed by remote side and which are received using `file_put_contents(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

```
csv=0,"ITEM 1"
1,"ITEM 2&CO"
2,"ITEM 3"
```

When I do `file_put_contents('file.txt', $_POST['csv']);` I get this truncated output to local file (note that it is missing double qoutes and file ends at this point):

```
0,"ITEM 1"
1,"ITEM 2
```

When I do `file_put_contents('file.txt', print_r($_POST['csv'], true));` This time text is strangely modified and ampersand is replaced by new line, 3 tabs and bracket:

```
[csv] => 0,"ITEM 1"
1,"ITEM 2
            [CO,"
2,"ITEM 3"
```

I have no idea why is this happening, as I thought that $_POST is not altered in any way. But apparently it is. Thank you in advance for any hints or ideas why is this happening and how to access $_POST['csv'] so it is not modified.

P.S.: I think that it shouldn't matter, but I will just mention that webserver used is nginx.

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($_POST);`? The `&` is usually part of the query string, so it could be getting messed up.

Comment: @aynber `var_dump($_POST);` returns almost the same as print_r, that is `1,"ITEM 2 "     "[CO,"` instead of `1,"ITEM 2&CO"`

Comment: Yep, it looks ike the `&` is being used as a query string separator. Check how you're submitting your form so that the `&` can be passed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to send a csv file as url encoded data without url encoding the data. The & is a special character which separates variables.

The proper data should be

```
csv=0%2C%22ITEM%201%22%0A1%2C%22ITEM%202%26CO%22%0A2%2C%22ITEM%203%22
```

The `%26` is the & encoded.

Where ever this data is posting from needs to url encode the data before sending it.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense now. However, I am not in control of sending side. If I will not be able to convince them to make a change to their data, is there a way around it in PHP to handle such non-standard situation ?

Comment: If the data is just `csv=<some data>`, just clip off the `csv=` part and you have your data.